# R: Change width of entire datatable in Rmd

Tags: css, r, datatable, resize

I'm generating a report using R markdown that includes a datatable. I would like the resulting html to maintain some margins, rather than the table filling the whole width of the page.

I've tried including:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=5, fig.height=8)
```

I've tried this:

````
 ``` {r fig1, fig.height = 3, fig.width = 5, echo = FALSE, include=TRUE}
````

I've tried defining figure size in the header under output. I've played around with the column widths option in the data table itself.

Any suggestions?

Here's an example Rmd:

````
---
title: "Initial Data Check Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S', 'America/Chicago', T)`"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: yes
    theme: null
    highlight: null
    mathjax: null
params:
  client: "ClientName"

---

### Audit Table
Some text here

---

```{r table, echo = FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
data = mtcars

```

``` {r fig1, fig.height = 3, fig.width = 5, echo = FALSE, include=TRUE}
datatable(data)

```
````

Comment: You can use `datatable(data, options = list(scrollX = '300px'))` for example. Look for the scrollX option. If the table overflows the width you set you get a scrollbar, if the data fits anyway then you won't.

Comment: hmmm... I've added this line, and the table is still the width of the page, no scroll bar added and no margins on my page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would something like

````
<div style = "width:80%; height:auto; margin: auto;">
``` {r fig1, echo = FALSE, include=TRUE}
datatable(data)
```
</div>
````

work?